# Python Command Line Arguments Try/Except

Tags: python, command-line, python-2.6

I want to create a program that will take two command line arguments. The first being the name of a file to open for parsing and the second the flag -s. If the user provides the wrong number of arguments or the other argument is not -s then it will print the message "Usage: [-s] file_name" and terminate the program using exit.

Next, I want my program to attempt to open the file for reading. The program should open the file read each line and return a count of every float, integer, and other kinds of strings that are not ints or floats. However, if opening the file fails it should raise an exception and print "Unable to open [filename]" and quit using exit.

I've been looking up lots of stuff on the internet about command lines in Python but I've ended up more confused. So here's my attempt at it so far from what I've researched.

```
    from optparse import OptionParser  

    def command_line():
        parser = OptionParser()        
        parser.add_option("--file", "-s")                             

        options, args = parser.parse_args()
        if options.a and obtions.b:
            parser.error("Usage: [-s] file_name")

            exit

    def read_file():
        #Try:
            #Open input file
        #Except:
            #print "Unable to open [filename]"
            #Exit
```

Comment: Could you maybe state what it is you are confused about, or why you think what you tried didn't work?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @M.T I guess what I'm more confused about is the second part where I'll actually read the file and return something based off of that, when I run the code that I have so far it doesn't give me any errors so I guess that part seems to be working

Comment: Could you give some information on what you expect the code to do and what it does wrong/what your questions is?

Comment: For future reference, if you clearly recognize that your question has two separate elements (understanding optparse and file handling), it might be better to put them into two separate questions.

Comment: Okay I'll take that into consideration next time, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from optparse import OptionParser
import sys,os

def command_line():
    parser = OptionParser("%prog [-s] file_name")        
    parser.add_option("-s",dest="filename",
        metavar="file_name",help="my help message")                             

    options, args = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.filename:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()
    return options.filename

def read_file(fn):
    if os.path.isfile(fn):
        typecount = {}
        with open(fn) as f:
            for line in f:
                for i in line.split()
                    try:
                        t = type(eval(i))
                    except NameError:
                        t = type(i)
                    if t in typecount:
                        typecount[t] += 1
                    else:
                        typecount[t] = 1
    else:
        print( "Unable to open {}".format(fn))
        sys.exit()

    print(typecount)

read_file(command_line())
```

So step by step:

- options.a is not defined unless you define an option `--a` or (preferably) set `dest="a"`.
- using the built-in `parser.print_help()` is better than making your own, you get `-h`/`--help` for free then.
- you never called your function `command_line`, therefore never getting any errors, as the syntax was correct. I set the commandline to pass only the filename as a return value, but there are better ways of doing this for when you have more options/arguments.

When it comes to `read_file`, instead of using try-except for the file I recommend using `os.path.isfile` which will check whether the file exists. This does not check that the file has the right format though.

We then create a dictionary of types, then loop over all lines and evaluate objects which are separated by whitespace(space,newline,tab). If your values are separated by eg. a comma, you need to use `line.split(',')`.

If you want to use the counts later in your script, you might want to return `typecount` instead of printing it.